# Constructing Diagonal Matrix for Given Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I want to find a basis for $R^n$ such that matrix representing reflection about the line spanned by [1, 2, 3] is diagonal.  I know that I need:

$T(v_1) = kv_1$ for some scalar $k$

$T(v_2) = kv_2$ for some scalar $k$

$T(v_3) = kv_3$ for some scalar $k$

(k's not nec. same)

So, $v_1 = [1, 2, 3]$ is an obvious choice since $v_1$ reflected about itself yields $v_1$ again.

For $v_2$, choose a vector that is perpendicular to $v_1$, so that $T(v_2) = -v_2$.  So let $v_2 = [3, 0, -1]$.

Finally, for $v_3$, I want a vector perpendicular to $v_1$ so that $T(v_3) = -v3$.  In order for my collection of vectors to span $R^3$, I need $v_3$ not to be a scalar multiple of $v_2$.  So let $v_3 = [2, -1, 0]$

Question: Do I need $v_3$ simply to be perpendicular to $v_1$ and not a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ or is what I did above correct (perpendicular and not a scalar multiple of $v_2$)?

Then for my matrix in terms of ${v_1, v_2, v_3}$, I have:

[
1 0  0

0 -1 0

0 0  -1
]

Does that look right?

Thanks for the help,
Mariogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a vector $v_3$ in the plane $\langle v_1\rangle^\perp$ so $v_3$ is perpendicular to $v_1$ and such that $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$. In this case your matrix is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of your question, it is not necessary for $v_3$ to be perpendicular to $v_2$.  However, if you were to change bases to the standard basis, you'll have the easiest time if $v_1,v_2,$ and $v_3$ are all mutually orthogonal (perpendicular) and of length 1.  In this case, the matrix with columns $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).